# Is Rails Haml precompiled or compiled on the fly on each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

So its quite simple my question, all I want to know is that. 
I want to try to see if using haml generated views adds overhead on each of my request and eventually dig deeper. Or maybe not because they are precompiled before deployment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Haml`](http://haml.info/) is very similar to `erb` - they're what are known as [preprocessors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor); meaning that your app will process the file as it's rendered

You may benefit from [reading up on Haml processing here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html)

Other than that, you may have to look at the Rails source to find out!!